# text processing in linux/bash, remove specific strings and join

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have multiple files that contain string like this:

```
result = [
    {
    key1 = value1
    key2 = value2
    key3 = {
           subkey3 = subvalue3
           }

    },
    {
    key3 = value3
    key4 = value4
    }
]
```

I want to merge those file become 1 file. so here what I did.

1. get all value inside result using`sed -i '/result\|\]\|\[/d' file`
2. I  append the output to a file but inside `result = []`

   result = [

   ]

but I don't know how, and I need to make sure there is comma `,` separated between each output from file.

Comment: Bash is probably the wrong tool for the job. If you remove the grouping, you will get a key name collision (example "key3").

Comment: @Fixlensmith : It is not clear to me from your description, how the output file is supposed to look. Finally, it is not clear how the keys and value look like. After all you are going to write a parser, so unless you define exactly the syntax of your data structure, you can't parse it.

Comment: @user1934428 the output should look like my example above..
as i mention before, I have multiple file like that, and I want to merge to 1 file.

Comment: I see only that you have posted the **input**, and I don't see any definition of the syntax of the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of json objects something like this can be done

```
for file in ./file*; do sed 's/result\ =\ \[/{/' $file | sed 's/\]/},/'; done > output.file
```

This would result in an output which somewhat looks like this-

```
{
    {
    key1 = value1
    key2 = value2
    key3 = {
           subkey3 = subvalue3
           }

    },
    {
    key3 = value3
    key4 = value4
    }
},
{
    {
    key1 = value1
    key2 = value2
    key3 = {
           subkey3 = subvalue3
           }

    },
    {
    key3 = value3
    key4 = value4
    }
},
```

To convert this to proper json-

1. Add a "[" to the beginning of the output file
2. at the end of the output file, replace the very last "," a "]" character.

Hopefully, This solves what you're trying to get done.